# WPF WebBrowser - Not opening Plugin Content

Tags: wpf, flash, plugins, browser, powerpoint

I am using a WPF Web Browser to show some PDF, Flash... files, the problem is that it works great in some computers, while on others it WebBrowser says it does not have the Flash plugin installed or the others...

I always thought that the WPF WebControl would pick up all the plugins the IE had installed, but for some reason it is not working properly. The stangest thing is that it works on some testing machines, that aparently have the same configurations.

Do you guys have any idea as to why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar issue, I was testing the same on multiple nodes, 32 bit and 64 bit ones. 64 bit Machines have separate internet explorer for 64 bit edition, you have to install a flash player for that also.